# Why this simple keras 3 class classifier is predicting only one class instead of other classes?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create a simple 3 class deep learning classifier using keras as follows:

```
clf = Sequential()
clf.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', input_dim=NUM_OF_FEATURES))
clf.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
clf.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
clf.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))


# Model Compilation
clf.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
             loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Training the model
clf.fit(X_train,
         y_train,
         epochs=10,
         batch_size=16,
         validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

How after training while predicting, it is only predicting the same class (class 1) out of the 3 classes ALWAYS.

Is my network architecture not correct?

I am new to deep learning and AI.

Comment: Please, provide the part of your code where you compile your model.

Comment: @Chicodelarosa updated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a network to classify three classes, your last dense layer should have three output nodes. In the example, the last dense layer has one output node.

```
clf = Sequential()
clf.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', input_dim=NUM_OF_FEATURES))
clf.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
clf.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
clf.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

For each input sample, the output will be three values, all of which sum to one. These represent the probabilities that the input belongs to each class.

Regarding the loss function, if you want to use cross entropy, you have a choice between sparse categorical cross entropy and categorical cross entropy. The latter expects ground truth labels to be one-hot encoded (you can use `tf.one_hot` for this). In other words, the shape of the labels is the same as the shape as the network's output. Sparse categorical cross entropy, on the other hand, expects labels with a rank N-1, where N is the rank of the neural network's output. In order words, these are the labels *before* one-hot encoding.

When the model is used for inference, the predicted class values can be retrieved with argmax of the last dimension of the predictions.

```
predictions = clf.predict(x)
classes = predictions.argmax(-1)
```

Comment: But with last dense layer with 3 output gives me the following error: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible`

Comment: It could be due to your loss function. Are your values for `y_train` integers 0, 1, and 2? If so, you should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` for your loss function. `categorical_crossentropy` expects one-hot encoded labels, whereas `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` expects non-one-hot labels.

Comment: which is better? `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` or `categorical_crossentropy`?

Comment: They compute the same loss (i.e., cross entropy) but expect labels in different forms. `categorical_crossentropy` expects one-hot encoded labels (2D in your case), and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` expects non-one-hot encoded labels (1D in your case).

Comment: ok, but `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` produces a matrix of float values `(array([[0.7737731 , 0.19874486, 0.02748196],
       [0.86113244, 0.12877706, 0.01009052],
       [0.9258943 , 0.07132111, 0.00278455],
       ...,
       [0.8239085 , 0.15966693, 0.01642458],
       [0.80182225, 0.1772431 , 0.02093465],
       [0.9042275 , 0.0910617 , 0.00471088]], dtype=float32))`. I wanted to get the predicted class labels as 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: That's not the output of the loss function, that seems to be the output of the last layer of the model. See the last part of my answer. You can use `numpy.argmax` to get the class label. That function will get the index of the largest value.